# validar sesión con números en tablas de mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de validar un inicio de sesión para los estudiantes que tengo en mi base de datos que no tienen nombre de usuario si no que su usuario y contraseña son sus mismos documentos.

Mi tabla de `estudiantes` se divide en dos... Los estudiantes que tienen su usuario y contraseña, por ejemplo: María José Pérez, el usuario sería **mjperez**, y la contraseña es la que ellos eligen.

Y para los estudiantes que no tienen usuario ni contraseña, su usuario y contraseña son su documento de identidad, por ejemplo: Luisa Fernanda, **Usuario:** 123456789 / **Contraseña:** 123456789.

Aquí el código.

```
                        if($perfil != 1) 
                            {// en este punto se valida si el estudiante esta en la base de datos y si es asi debe entrar con la cedula

                            //echo "prueba<br>";

                            $estudiante = intval($estudiante);

                            include 'conectar.php';
                            $sql = 'select * from estudiantes where estudiante="'.$estudiante.'"';

                            //echo $sql;

                            //echo "<br>estudiante:".$estudiante;
                            //echo "<br>Contrasena:".$contrasena;
                            //echo "<br>Perfil:".$contrasena;

                            $res = mysql_query($sql,$con);
                            $row = mysql_num_rows($res);


                            $_SESSION["estudiante"] = $estudiante;
                            $_SESSION["Perfil"] = $row["Perfil"];
                            $_SESSION["Grado"] = $row["Grado"];
                            $_SESSION["Nombres"] = $row["Nombres"];
                            //echo $sql;

                            if ($row["estudiante"] == $estudiante and $row["Contrasena"] == $contrasena)
                                {
                                $total = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM estudiantes WHERE estudiante ='$estudiante'"));
                                if($total==0)
                                    {
                                    $total = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM relacion_votos WHERE estudiante ='$estudiante'"));
                                    if($total==0)
                                        {
                                        header("Location: menu.php");
                                        }else
                                            {
                                            header("Location: registrado.php");
                                            }
                                    }else
                                        {
                                        header("Location: index.php");
                                        }
                                }else
                                    {
                                    header("Location: index.php");
                                    }
                            }
```

Resalto que los estudiantes que tienen usuario y contraseña pueden ingresar sin problemas, pero los que tienen el número como usuario, no pueden ingresar.

Comment: Como es tu tabla? como es el form? ya que por ejemplo ahí estudiantes ya está declarada pero no se sabe con qué

Comment: Los estudiantes que tienen usuario ingresan por un directorio diferente porque son los estudiantes de la universidad... Los otros que vienen con el documento, son estudiantes que vienen a reforzar materias y a presentar pruebas diferentes.

Comment: @Sergio1871 y no tengo una tabla, es una sesión de validación a la plataforma para ingresar a mi clase, cuando ingresan pueden ver el resto de menús que tengo para las clases.

Comment: Yo me referia a tu tabla de mysql, por otro lado no dices de donde sacas la información por ejemplo ahí tienes la variable contrasena y jamás se ve donde se declara